# Is this a tried alternative to word embedding for NLP?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-classification, language-model

I'm searching for research related to my idea, but apparently cannot articulate it well enough to the search engines to show me what's been published on this.

My idea: in a deep learning context (text classification), instead of inputting the text as integer vectors representing words in a vocabulary, which get substituted with dense vectors (word embeddings), what if instead, you represent each phrase almost like how a vector of "pixels" represent an image (then use 2d convolutions)? For example, each character, digit, and symbol get an integer value, just like how pixels are represented. So `abc` becomes `0, 1, 2`. The phrase could be formatted as a rectangle at word boundaries or something, but the gist of it, a phrase is formulated as a 2d array where each element is a character from some character set.

Is this a known/tried approach, and what name does it go by? From its apparent lack of popularity, I assume this formulation is far worse than word embeddings, but I'm curious about it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about a character-level model. Several models consider characters or substrings of words, e.g. FastText [1], but I don't know if any apply convolutions.

[1] P. Bojanowski, E. Grave, A. Joulin, and T. Mikolov, ‘Enriching Word Vectors with Subword Information’, TACL, vol. 5, pp. 135–146, Dec. 2017, doi: 10.1162/tacl_a_00051.

Answer (score 0):

It has never been tried as far as I know. And the reason is that, IMHO, it would give you inconsistent results. I am talking in particular about unwanted arithmetic properties of such vector.

Do you want to represent an `a`, `b`, `c` vector of letters `{1,2,3}` knowing that

`a < b < c`  ?

This makes sens with ints, not with char/tokens.

The good news is you can still use 2d conv, once you assembled embedding vectors into larger phrase vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this has been done, in fact there was a period of time before large recurrent models could be reliably trained (and before Transformers were invented) where such methods were state of the art. Paper: ["Character-level Convolutional Networks for Text Classification"](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2015/hash/250cf8b51c773f3f8dc8b4be867a9a02-Abstract.html)